# angular json with multiple indexes parse after list then and select one by id and list him details

Tags: json, angular, typescript, parsing

I have a question to solve a problem here at work.

I have an API that lists the CUPS of a client that works with soccer championships and the api gives me an array with several championships that he has already participated and is participating.

I already listed and I can access the page with the specific ID of the event, but now I don't know how to handle the specific data of that event. I can store it in local storage but I don't know how to treat the array (example below) and separate things based on

```
id_evento
```

```
[
    {
        "id_cliente_evento": 46290,
        "trechos": null,
        "jogador": 1,
        "stop": 1,
        "tp_cliente": "ADT",
        "data": "2022-08-18T12:25:08.000000Z",
        "contrato": 2,
        "bilhete_aereo": 0,
        "loc": null,
        "loc2": null,
        "loc3": null,
        "cancelado": null,
        "solicitacao_reembolso": null,
        "emissao_reembolso": null,
        "observacao_reembolso": null,
        "envio_email_boleto": null,
        "vip": null,
        "super_vip": null,
        "id_receita_erpflex": null,
        "bilhete_loja": 0,
        "voucher_loja": 0,
        "contrato_pdf": "PENDENTE",
        "evento": {
            "id_evento": 73,
            "ds_evento": "Copa AFIA Portugal - Cascais 2023",
            "local": null,
            "codigo": "CPC23",
            "data": "2023-05-26T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "data_final": "2023-06-04T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "infos": "<p class=\"Normal tm5 tm6\"><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\"><span class=\"tm8\">Copa AFIA  Portugal - Cascais 2023</span><span class=\"tm9\"><br><br><br></span></span><span class=\"tm10\">Período: de  27 de maio  a 04  de junho de 2023 </span><span class=\"tm11\"><br></span><span class=\"tm10\"><br><br></span><em><span class=\"tm12\">Incluso no Produto:</span><span class=\"tm8\" style=\"font-weight: bolder;\"><br></span><span class=\"tm9\" style=\"font-weight: bolder;\"><br></span></em></p><ul class=\"Normal tm5 tm13\"><li class=\"tm14\"><span class=\"tm10\"><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">Passagem aérea ida e volta</span> em classe econômica voando TAP : aeroporto de origem Brasil  / aeroporto Lisboa / Portugal  / aeroporto de origem Brasil; <br><br></span></li><li class=\"Normal tm5 tm14\"><span class=\"tm10\"><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">6 ou 7 noites de hospedagem</span> no hotel </span><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">Vila Galé Cascais ou Vila Galé Estoril </span><span class=\"tm10\">em</span><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\"> </span><span class=\"tm10\">apartamento duplo ou triplo; <br><br></span></li><li class=\"Normal tm5 tm14\"><span class=\"tm10\">Transfer aeroporto Lisboa / hotel </span><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\">Vila Galé </span><span class=\"tm10\"> / aeroporto Lisboa - in/out<br><br></span></li><li class=\"Normal tm5 tm14\"><span class=\"tm10\">Sistema <b>Meia Pensão  - </b>café da manhã e jantar com vinho ou água</span><span class=\"tm10\">;<br><br></span></li><li class=\"Normal tm5 tm14\"><span class=\"tm10\">Kit Viagem AFIA;<br><br></span></li><li class=\"Normal tm5 tm14\"><span class=\"tm7\"></span><span class=\"tm10\">Programação de eventos AFIA</span><span class=\"tm11\"><br><br>* (triplo = 3ª pessoa em sofá Cama). </span></li><li class=\"Normal tm5 tm16\"><span class=\"tm11\"></span><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\"><em>Valores de referência em pré-lançamento:</em></span><em><br></em><span class=\"tm10\">Banda tarifária desde R$ 11.990,00 a R$ 12.490,00 (à vista) por pessoa<br>Condição: parcelamentos em até 12x sem juros<br></span><span class=\"tm11\"><br></span></li><li class=\"Normal tm5 tm16\"><span class=\"tm11\"></span><span style=\"font-weight: bolder;\"><span class=\"tm15\">Observação:</span><em><span class=\"tm17\"><br></span></em></span><span class=\"tm10\">- não incluso taxas: de embarque, de emissão e de turismo, que serão cobradas posteriormente;<br>- taxa de inscrição esportiva não incluída <br>- lugares sujeitos a disponibilidade e alterações de tarifa sem prévio aviso.</span></li></ul>",
            "infos_eng": "<span id=\"docs-internal-guid-a6109511-7fff-17a9-53ea-4ba1fb3d6d68\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:8pt;\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Copa AFIA&nbsp; Portugal - Cascais 2023</span></p><br><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:8pt;\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Period </span><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">: from 27th May to 3rd June of 2023</span></p><br><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:8pt;\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Package including:</span></p><ul style=\"margin-bottom: 0px; padding-inline-start: 48px;\"><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">TAP, round trip air ticket economic class with one piece of luggage (23kg): Berlin / Lisbon / Berlin.</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">7 night’s stay at the Vila Galé Estoril (or equivalent) in a double or a triple* use appartment.&nbsp;</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Round trip group transfer Lisbon Airport / Hotel / Lisbon Airport;</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Half Board basis: Breakfast + dinner (drinks included: wine and water only);</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Travel kit (AFIA’s tailor made bag, Event’s T-shirt, Travel documentation and Athlete’s uniform);</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:12pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">AFIA event’s tailor made program at the hotel;</span><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\"><br></span><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\"><br></span><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">* (triple occupancy = 3rd person on a sofa-bed).&nbsp; Children under 16 years old, not permitted by the hotel.</span></p></li></ul><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:12pt;\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Reference pre-launching price range (per person);</span></p><ul style=\"margin-bottom: 0px; padding-inline-start: 48px;\"><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Price range: 1.300EUR to 1.490EUR</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:12pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">AFIA special conditions: 2 instalments; </span><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\"><br><br></span></p></li></ul><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:12pt;\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-weight: 700; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">REMARKS:</span></p><ul style=\"margin-bottom: 0px; padding-inline-start: 48px;\"><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">NOT INCLUDED: Approx: 70EUR (airport, issue and tourism taxes, to be confirmed at ticketing issuance);</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">NOT INCLUDED: Sports fee: 169EUR (per athlete)</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">All subject to availability and price changing with no prior notice.</span></p></li><li dir=\"ltr\" style=\"list-style-type: disc; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre;\" aria-level=\"1\"><p dir=\"ltr\" style=\"line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:12pt;\" role=\"presentation\"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;\">CHILDREN NOT PERMITTED on this hotel&nbsp; (under 16 years).</span></p></li></ul></span>",
            "infos_deu": null,
            "infos_esp": null,
            "intencao_stop": false,
            "pre_inscricao": false,
            "taxa_esportiva": null,
            "data_adesao": null,
            "dias_adesao": null,
            "alimentacao": null,
            "incluso_pacote": {
                "periodo": "19 a 26 de dezembro",
                "noites": "6 ou 7 noites",
                "valores": "de R$ 5.290,00 a R $5.690,00",
                "inclui": [
                    {
                        "nome": "Alimentação",
                        "descricao": "All Inclusive"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Tipo de passagem",
                        "descricao": "Classe econômica"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Hotel",
                        "descricao": "Vila Galé Cascais ou Vila Galé Estoril"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Transfer Aeroporto",
                        "descricao": "Lisboa / hotel Vila Galé  / aeroporto Lisboa - in/out"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Kit Viagem AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Programação de eventos AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id_os_erpflex": null,
            "id_servico_erpflex": null
        },
        "grupo": {
            "id_grupo": 2302,
            "chave": "PRE-8723",
            "chave_ativa": true,
            "apenas_jogador": false,
            "lista_espera": false,
            "categoria": {
                "id_categoria": 10,
                "descricao": "Sapphire",
                "idade_minima": 65
            },
            "descricao": {
                "id_ds_grupo": 82,
                "descricao": "Banespa - SP"
            }
        },
    },
    {
        "id_cliente_evento": 44424,
        "trechos": null,
        "jogador": 1,
        "stop": 0,
        "tp_cliente": "ADT",
        "data": "2021-12-27T20:10:48.000000Z",
        "contrato": 2,
        "bilhete_aereo": 0,
        "loc": "ZK4U5D",
        "loc2": "AW8Y8B",
        "loc3": null,
        "cancelado": null,
        "solicitacao_reembolso": null,
        "emissao_reembolso": null,
        "observacao_reembolso": null,
        "envio_email_boleto": null,
        "vip": 0,
        "super_vip": 0,
        "id_receita_erpflex": 17551352,
        "bilhete_loja": 0,
        "voucher_loja": 0,
        "contrato_pdf": "GERADO",
        "evento": {
            "id_evento": 69,
            "ds_evento": "Copa AFIA Brasil - Pernambuco 2022",
            "local": null,
            "codigo": "CBP22",
            "data": "2022-10-08T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "data_final": "2022-10-15T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "infos_eng": null,
            "infos_deu": null,
            "infos_esp": null,
            "intencao_stop": false,
            "pre_inscricao": false,
            "taxa_esportiva": null,
            "data_adesao": null,
            "dias_adesao": null,
            "alimentacao": null,
            "incluso_pacote": {
                "periodo": "19 a 26 de dezembro",
                "noites": "6 ou 7 noites",
                "valores": "de R$ 5.290,00 a R $5.690,00",
                "inclui": [
                    {
                        "nome": "Alimentação",
                        "descricao": "All Inclusive"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Tipo de passagem",
                        "descricao": "Classe econômica"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Hotel",
                        "descricao": "Vila Galé Cascais ou Vila Galé Estoril"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Transfer Aeroporto",
                        "descricao": "Lisboa / hotel Vila Galé  / aeroporto Lisboa - in/out"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Kit Viagem AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Programação de eventos AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id_os_erpflex": 3432347,
            "id_servico_erpflex": 4714474
        },
    },
    {
        "id_cliente_evento": 41852,
        "trechos": null,
        "jogador": 1,
        "stop": 1,
        "tp_cliente": "ADT",
        "data": "2021-02-22T17:56:13.000000Z",
        "contrato": 2,
        "bilhete_aereo": 0,
        "loc": "WRSZMT",
        "loc2": null,
        "loc3": null,
        "cancelado": null,
        "solicitacao_reembolso": null,
        "emissao_reembolso": null,
        "observacao_reembolso": null,
        "envio_email_boleto": null,
        "vip": 0,
        "super_vip": 0,
        "id_receita_erpflex": null,
        "bilhete_loja": 1,
        "voucher_loja": 1,
        "contrato_pdf": "GERADO",
        "evento": {
            "id_evento": 66,
            "ds_evento": "Copa AFIA Espanha - Catalunha 2022",
            "local": null,
            "codigo": "CEC22",
            "data": "2022-05-26T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "data_final": "2022-06-04T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "infos": null,
            "infos_eng": null,
            "infos_deu": null,
            "infos_esp": null,
            "intencao_stop": false,
            "pre_inscricao": false,
            "taxa_esportiva": null,
            "data_adesao": null,
            "dias_adesao": null,
            "alimentacao": null,
            "incluso_pacote": {
                "periodo": "19 a 26 de dezembro",
                "noites": "6 ou 7 noites",
                "valores": "de R$ 5.290,00 a R $5.690,00",
                "inclui": [
                    {
                        "nome": "Alimentação",
                        "descricao": "All Inclusive"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Tipo de passagem",
                        "descricao": "Classe econômica"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Hotel",
                        "descricao": "Vila Galé Cascais ou Vila Galé Estoril"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Transfer Aeroporto",
                        "descricao": "Lisboa / hotel Vila Galé  / aeroporto Lisboa - in/out"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Kit Viagem AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Programação de eventos AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id_os_erpflex": null,
            "id_servico_erpflex": null
        },
        "grupo": {
            "id_grupo": 2030,
            "chave": "PRE-5148",
            "chave_ativa": true,
            "apenas_jogador": false,
            "lista_espera": true,
            "categoria": {
                "id_categoria": 10,
                "descricao": "Sapphire",
                "idade_minima": 65
            },
            "descricao": {
                "id_ds_grupo": 82,
                "descricao": "Banespa - SP"
            }
        },
    },
    {
        "id_cliente_evento": 39436,
        "trechos": null,
        "jogador": 1,
        "stop": 0,
        "tp_cliente": "ADT",
        "data": "2020-07-14T15:33:28.000000Z",
        "contrato": 2,
        "bilhete_aereo": 1,
        "loc": "JQGHKK",
        "loc2": "LILKPM",
        "loc3": null,
        "cancelado": null,
        "solicitacao_reembolso": null,
        "emissao_reembolso": null,
        "observacao_reembolso": null,
        "envio_email_boleto": null,
        "vip": 0,
        "super_vip": 0,
        "id_receita_erpflex": null,
        "bilhete_loja": 1,
        "voucher_loja": 1,
        "contrato_pdf": "GERADO",
        "evento": {
            "id_evento": 64,
            "ds_evento": "Copa AFIA Brasil - Ceará 2021",
            "local": null,
            "codigo": "CBC21",
            "data": "2021-10-09T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "data_final": "2021-10-16T03:00:00.000000Z",
            "infos_deu": null,
            "infos_esp": null,
            "intencao_stop": false,
            "pre_inscricao": false,
            "taxa_esportiva": null,
            "data_adesao": null,
            "dias_adesao": null,
            "alimentacao": null,
            "incluso_pacote": {
                "periodo": "19 a 26 de dezembro",
                "noites": "6 ou 7 noites",
                "valores": "de R$ 5.290,00 a R $5.690,00",
                "inclui": [
                    {
                        "nome": "Alimentação",
                        "descricao": "All Inclusive"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Tipo de passagem",
                        "descricao": "Classe econômica"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Hotel",
                        "descricao": "Vila Galé Cascais ou Vila Galé Estoril"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Transfer Aeroporto",
                        "descricao": "Lisboa / hotel Vila Galé  / aeroporto Lisboa - in/out"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Kit Viagem AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    },
                    {
                        "nome": "Programação de eventos AFIA",
                        "descricao": "Incluso"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id_os_erpflex": 2894432,
            "id_servico_erpflex": 4110835
        },
    },
```

In this page I will select the Cup and pass the id_evento at the URL
I save the array on local storage and now I need to separate this expecific id_evento content in another local on local storage to use the details in cup details page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDdwG.png)

1- How can I get the id_evento in the URL and save the value to use in cup details?
2- How can I save the details of this expecific id_evento to use the details in cup details?

Here's my select-cup.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JETcl.png)

Here's my select-cup.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQHJB.png)

Let me explain with images, i have this array with 10 objects: https://prnt.sc/I9pHqvnIvZaF

In each one of then i have an object Evento, and they 're diferent.

I have separeted this events in local storage but i need to separate eache one by id_evento https://prnt.sc/Z0gb4qbBIzc2

I need to use the details in another page, so when I select one here: https://prnt.sc/DWlo4yhIPNQZ i pass the id with the URL but i can't separate the name and other fings in local storage to use in the internal page of each one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert your cups array into a id array you can do something like the following:

```
const bigCupsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourKey"));
const idArray = bigCupsArray.map((cup) => cup.evento.id_evento);
console.log(idArray) // should looks like [73, 69, 66, ...]
```

After this you could work with the id_evento array as you want.

Comment: Let me explain with images, i have this array with 10 objects: https://prnt.sc/I9pHqvnIvZaF

In each one of then i have an object Evento, and they 're diferent.

I have separeted this events in local storage but i need to separate eache one by id_evento https://prnt.sc/Z0gb4qbBIzc2

I need to use the details in another page, so when I select one here: https://prnt.sc/DWlo4yhIPNQZ i pass the id with the URL but i can't separate the name and other fings in local storage to use in the internal page of each one

Comment: so you want the full evento object instead of only the id?

Comment: Yes, but I don't no how to do this when the array have multiple indexes, and de id_evento is inside the evento array prnt.sc/DEPQxQB1yg7c So for exempla I want to separarate the evento [0]>evento>id_evento: 73(and only the content of evento>id_evento: 73)

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the financial extract. I talked with the other responsible of this project and he will do some adjustments in API. But I want to know if is possible do that or no

Comment: then just return `cup.evento` in the map function instead of the id and you will get a array of all evento